# Pandas: accessing the next row (like LEAD in Oracle)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a log of users interactions with a website:

```
id    user_id    action_type    comment    timestamp
```

Not all *action_type*s are the same. Some of them of more importance and some are of less:

```
PURCHASE (important, primary)
VISIT_PAGE (less important, secondary)
```

I want to transform my table into the following:

```
id    user_id    action_type    comment    timestamp    next_id    goal_id
```

Where:

> **next_id** is the next action for the user with closest timestamp in the future
>
> **goal_id** is the  next *primary* action for the user with closest timestamp in future

For example, if user has the following history:

```
/ -> /toys -> /toys/lego -> /toys/lego/ABC001 -> PURCHASE
```

Then I have the following table:

```
id    user_id    action_type    comment            timestamp    next_id    goal_id
1     1          VISIT_PAGE     /                  123456789    2          5
2     1          VISIT_PAGE     /toys              123457789    3          5
3     1          VISIT_PAGE     /toys/lego         123458889    4          5
4     1          VISIT_PAGE     /toys/lego/ABC001  123459889    5          5
5     1          PURCHASE                          123460889    NULL       5
```

Can this be accomplished using *Pandas*? It's pretty much like LEAD function in Oracle.

Comment: `pandas.Series.shift`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some list of primary actions types: Here is a dirty way to do it. Note I didn't use any pandas magic but hopefully this gives you some ideas:

```
primaries = set("two") # set of primary actions

# an example dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1], 
              ["one"] * 4 +  ["two"] * 1, 
              ["/", "toys", "toys/lego", "toys/lego/ABC001"],
              [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005]]
            ).T
df.columns = ["user_id", "action_type", "comment", "timestamp"]

# reindexing to make it look like your sample
df.index = range(1, len(df)+1)
df.head()

nt = [] # next_ids
gl = [] # goal_ids

for i in df.iterrows():
    if i[1]["action_type"] not in primaries:
        nt.extend([i[0]+1])
    else:
        nt.extend([None])
        gl.extend([i[0]] * len(nt))

new_df = pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame({"next_id" : nt], "goal_id" : ids[gl]}))
```

Comment: Might work if sorted by timestamp, tnx! Still looking for *Pandagick!* way of doing it)